# "Odd number of elements in hash assignment" - simple example code included, why does it happen?

Tags: perl, hash

Basically when I shift a hash to work with it in a subroutine I get the error: Odd number of elements in hash assignment. Am I supposed to use a hash reference instead if I wish to pass hashes to subroutines?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my ($a, $b, $c, %hash) = &getVals() ;
&run($a,$b,$c,%hash) ;


sub getVals() {
    $hash{"f"} = "abc" ;
    $a = "A" ;
    $b = "B" ;
    $c = "C" ;
    return ($a, $b, $c, %hash) ;
}


sub run() {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;
    my $c = shift;
    my %hash = shift; #error here 


    #do stuff here. . . 
}
```

Comment: Don't use prototypes (`()`), much less incorrect ones you need to override with `&` later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shift` removes the first element from `@_` and returns it. You can either use the reference, or just assign the whole list (after shifting the single elements) to the hash:

```
my %hash = @_;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to pass hashes to subroutines. Subroutines can take a list of scalars as arguments. (It's also the only thing they can return.)

`getVals` returns 5 scalars:

1. `A`
2. `B`
3. `C`
4. `f`
5. `abc`

`shift` returns the first scalar in `@_` after removing it. You want to assign all the remaining scalars in `@_` (`f` and `abc`) to the hash, not just the first one.

```
sub run {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;
    my $c = shift;
    my %hash = @_;
    ...
}
```

or

```
sub run {
    my ($a, $b, $c, %hash) = @_;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my ($a, $b, $c, %hash) = &getVals() ;
&run($a,$b,$c,%hash) ;

sub getVals() {
    $hash{"f"} = "abc" ;
    $a = "A" ;
    $b = "B" ;
    $c = "C" ;
    return ($a, $b, $c, %hash) ;
}

sub run() {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;
    my $c = shift;
    my %hash = @_; 

    #.............
}
```